# Get first row of an ordered Gtk TreeView(Gtk#)

Tags: c#, gtk, gtk#

I have a Gtk# TreeView with one visible column whose Model contains 3 values (text for the visible column, a value to sort the tree on and a reference to the base object). Here is the code:

```
internal class JpgTreeView : TreeView
{
    private readonly ListStore _store = new ListStore(typeof(string), typeof(int), typeof(ITreeViewChoice));
    private TreeModelSort _sortedModel;

    private enum Column
    {
        Text,
        SortValue,
        Value
    }

    public JpgTreeView()
    {
        var valueColumn = new TreeViewColumn();
        AppendColumn(valueColumn);
        var visisbleColumnTextRenderer = new CellRendererText();
        valueColumn.PackStart(visisbleColumnTextRenderer, true);
        valueColumn.AddAttribute(visisbleColumnTextRenderer, "text", (int) Column.Text);

        _sortedModel = new TreeModelSort(_store);
        _sortedModel.SetSortColumnId((int) Column.SortValue, SortType.Descending);
        _sortedModel.SetSortFunc((int) Column.SortValue, (model, a, b) =>
        {
            var aval = (int) model.GetValue(a, (int) Column.SortValue);
            var bval = (int) model.GetValue(b, (int) Column.SortValue);
            return aval.CompareTo(bval);
        });
        Model = _sortedModel;
    }
```

The sorting works correctly but the `_store.GetIterFirst` function always retrieves the original first row (i.e. the first row of the unsorted list). `_sortedModel.GetIterFirst` returns the following error message:

`gtk_list_store_get_value: assertion 'iter_is_valid (iter, list_store)' failed`

I'm populating the TreeView using this function:

```
public void SetChoices(IEnumerable<ITreeViewChoice> choices)
{
    _store.Clear();
    foreach (var choice in choices)
    {
        _store.AppendValues(choice.GetChoiceText(), 1, choice);
    }
}
```

How do I get the first row of the sorted list?

Comment: Can you provide the full example? `GetIterFirst()` method return a bool value, check that value. Do you happen to initilize iter before liststore is poped with values?

Comment: Your JpgTreeView class is confusing. It inherit from TreeView, so it must be a TreeView. But you have a liststore in it. From your example, the treeview doesn't seem to be associated with the liststore.

Comment: I updated it to use a TreeStore. Here is a link to the project: https://github.com/jpginc/JPGTree/blob/74a7e00e59279515cd759d463676e76e5b46677b/ConsoleApp1/Gui/JpgTreeView.cs#L210

Comment: I see my mistake now. I was confused between the TreeStore and the TreeModelSort. Getting the row from the TreeModelSort works correctly, but I was trying to extract the value of the TreeModelSort's row using the TreeStore which isn't valid. I'll add an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_sortedModel.GetIterFirst` is the correct way to retrieve the first row of an ordered Gtk TreeView (TreeModelSort)

The issue I was having is that I was using the row returned from the TreeModelSort in the ListStore which isn't valid. i.e. this is correct:

```
_sortedModel.GetIterFirst(out var iter);
var value = _sortedModel.GetValue(iter, (int) Column.Value);
```

And this is incorrect (what i was doing):

```
_sortedModel.GetIterFirst(out var iter);
var value = _store.GetValue(iter, (int) Column.Value);
```